# Prevent caching across browser instances in Android (using zxing)

Tags: android, caching, redirect, zxing

I'm trying to prevent Android caching redirected web pages. I'm mostly successful but there is a failure mode in an unusual circumstance involving barcode reading*. I'd appreciate some help with understanding what's going on.

My scenario is:

(1) Place constant URL in a QR code (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_code), let's say it's http://foo.com/bar.

(2) At the server, when the GET on that URL arrives, redirect with cache control headers like so (excuse the PHP :-)):

```
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");
header("Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT"); // Date in the past
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header('Location: ' . generateAOneTimeURL(), TRUE, 307 );
```

(3) In addition, when the content is served from any such one-time URL, I use the same cache-control headers in its META tag.

(4) I'm using Android's own barcode scanner, zxing. This displays the URL it has read from the barcode, as a hyperlink for the user to click to view the web page.

(5) If the user hits Android's back button to get back to scanning mode and scans the same barcode again, everything works fine: when the user clicks the same URL again, they're redirected to a new one-time URL, as intended.

(6) However, if the user presses Android's home button, and clicks on the barcode scanner app again, the above directives are ignored:

(A) The user is shown a page at the *previous* one-time URL

(B) It does *not* do another GET against that URL, it just shows what that URL showed before.

Am I missing a cache-control directive that might help me, or is this a peculiarity (bug?) of how clicks on URLs are handled from different instances of the same app?

Thanks in advance.

Tim

*The important part is that it's an app from which a webview is launched, rather than that it's the zxing barcode reader per se.